# Add child to a MenuItem within a group in a NavigationView

Tags: android, android-menu, navigationview

I already checked some questions but none has a really answer of what I'm looking for.

Basically I'm trying to add an item child to an item parent, or simulate a tree of options in the lateral panel, something like the Google Play app does:

[image]

I tried this as a test in my XML file:

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:orderInCategory="0"
            android:id="@+id/nav_back"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp"
            android:title="Regresar a la pagina principal"
            />
</group>

<group android:checkableBehavior="single"
    android:id="@+id/groupTypes">
    <item
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:id="@+id/nav_negocios"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_local_convenience_store_black_48dp"
        android:title="@string/negocios" />
    <item
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:id="@+id/nav_hoteles"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_local_hotel_black_48dp"
        android:title="@string/hoteles" />
    <item
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:id="@+id/nav_bares"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_local_bar_black_48dp"
        android:title="@string/bares">

        <menu>
            <item
                android:orderInCategory="1"
                android:id="@+id/nav_barType1"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_local_bar_black_48dp"
                android:title="@string/restaurant" />
        </menu>

        </item>

    <item
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:id="@+id/nav_restaurant"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_restaurant_black_48dp"
        android:title="@string/restaurant" />
    <item
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:id="@+id/nav_destacado"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_stars_black_48dp"
        android:title="@string/destacado" />
</group>

<group android:title="@string/grupo2">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_taxi"
            android:orderInCategory="2"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_local_taxi_black_48dp"
            android:title="@string/mobility" />

    </menu>
</group>
```

And this is what I got:

[image]

The "Bares" item has changed to a category and the item inside is just adding as the original sequence in the group.

Also I tried using the `android:menuCategory="container"` and `android:menuCategory="secondary"`options but the result is the same.

```
<item
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:id="@+id/nav_bares"
        android:menuCategory="container"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_local_bar_black_48dp"
        android:title="@string/bares">

        <menu>
            <item
                android:orderInCategory="1"
                android:id="@+id/nav_barType1"
                android:menuCategory="secondary"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_local_bar_black_48dp"
                android:title="@string/restaurant" />
        </menu>

</item>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find such an API in source codes. I decompiled Play Store [apk file](http://www.androidapksfree.com/apk/google-play-store-apk-latest-version-download/) (version 7.7.17.O) with [androidtool](https://github.com/mortenjust/androidtool-mac).

### main.xml

```
<com.google.android.finsky.layout.play.FinskyDrawerLayout>
    <com.google.android.finsky.layout.InsetsFrameLayout>
    </com.google.android.finsky.layout.InsetsFrameLayout>
    <include layout="@layout/play_drawer_container" />
</com.google.android.finsky.layout.play.FinskyDrawerLayout>
```

### play_drawer_container.xml

```
<LinearLayout>
    <ListView android:id="@id/play_drawer_list" style="@style/PlayDrawerList" />
    <TextView android:id="@id/play_drawer_docked_action" android:visibility="gone" style="@style/PlayDrawerDockedAction" />
</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see, menu items are not set via `app:menu`. It's just a `ListView`.

You can also see the difference of view bounds when "Show layout bounds" is turned on:

[image]

[image]

If they have used the default `menu` items, you should have seen the boundaries matching.

So, answering to your question: it can be implemented with custom approach, menus have no such functionality.

**Update**

There are a number of ways to implement that kind of functionality:

1. Using `RecyclerView`
2. Using `ListView`
3. Using `ScrollView`

If there are few items in the list, which won't need recycling functionality, than you can stick with `ScrollView`. Otherwise, prefer either `RecyclerView` or `ListView`, where each of item has its own row item xml.

Comment: Fellows, when you downvote please describe the background of your decision. If you have a fair point I'll admit that and will edit/remove my answer. If your aim is to receive a bounty, tell me I'll upvote your answer.

Comment: Hey, sorry dude thats a good answer, I was in the penalty box, just refer or add some simple example and I'll choose your answer.

Comment: @BrandonZamudio, sorry, didn't get what you mean. What's penalty box? Why should I refer or add an example?

Comment: Because your answer says that it can be implemented with custom approach, so how to do that? or it warrants another question?

Comment: Didn't know about penalty box existence, thanks. `so how to do that?` I see your point. Will update the answer.

Comment: By the way, do you verify, that the approaches mentioned in other answers do not work? Because if the do - my answer is not correct and should **not** be accepted.

Comment: I did, these answer doesn't work or is not what I'm asking

Answer (score 0):

You need to surround your item with the menu, and then add the submenu below it. It might look like this:

```
 <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:orderInCategory="0"
            android:id="@+id/nav_back"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp"
            android:title="Regresar a la pagina principal"
            />
</group>

<group android:checkableBehavior="single"
    android:id="@+id/groupTypes">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:orderInCategory="1"
            android:id="@+id/nav_negocios"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_local_convenience_store_black_48dp"
            android:title="@string/negocios" />
        <item
            android:orderInCategory="1"
            android:id="@+id/nav_hoteles"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_local_hotel_black_48dp"
            android:title="@string/hoteles" />
        <item
            android:orderInCategory="1"
            android:id="@+id/nav_bares"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_local_bar_black_48dp"
            android:title="@string/bares">
              <menu>
                  <item
                      android:orderInCategory="1"
                      android:id="@+id/nav_barType1"
                      android:icon="@drawable/ic_local_bar_black_48dp"
                      android:title="@string/restaurant" />
              </menu>
        </item>
         <item
                android:orderInCategory="1"
                android:id="@+id/nav_restaurant"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_restaurant_black_48dp"
                android:title="@string/restaurant" />
         <item
                android:orderInCategory="1"
                android:id="@+id/nav_destacado"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_stars_black_48dp"
                android:title="@string/destacado" />
   </menu>
    </group>

    <group android:title="@string/grupo2">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_taxi"
                android:orderInCategory="2"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_local_taxi_black_48dp"
                android:title="@string/mobility" />

        </menu>
    </group>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with drop down menu or expandable list or simple lists which can be seen on click of menu options accordingly in navigation drawer instead of group.

Answer (score 0):

For your first approach, you can make a little edit. That SubItem is also an item an instead of putting everything in group you should put in an item. Try this example below:

```
 <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_category_electronics"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_email_black_24dp"
        android:title="Electronics">

        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_subcategory_laptops"
                android:icon="@drawable/laptop"
                android:title="Laptops" />

            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_subcategory_tablet"
                android:icon="@drawable/tablet3"
                android:title="Tablets" />

            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_category_phones"
                android:icon="@drawable/smartphone"
                android:title="Mobile Phones" />

            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_subcategory_gadgets"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_developer_mode_black_18dp"
                android:title="Gadgets" />
        </menu>
    </item>
```